# Switching from default native App to mobile website in browser

Tags: android, android-app-indexing

I've implemented some intent-filters in the manifest of my Android app, so it handles some specified links.

When a user opens the app via url, he has to pass a dialog where he can choose which app he wants to use. It's also possible to set the app to default, so the next time it's automatically opened by clicking on such link. This process can be also simplified on app installation using Google Digital Asset Links (Android >= 6.0), which sets the default app automatically.

The problem is, that a user might not always use the app, but also the mobile website. For that case, he has to turn off the default app somewhere in the settings (which is quite complicated for inexperienced android users) or just press the option "use once" on the dialog. On iOS you have the built-in option, that the user can go back to the mobile website easily by clicking on the "go back to mobile website"-arrow on the top bar (When the app was started via link in the browser before), afaik.

Is there a built-in function for Android too? How can I achieve that on Android without calling a new intent with the mobile website link? This would end up in another dialog, which I want to avoid.